# Meteor: Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project: Unknown package

Tags: meteor

What are the constraints that Meteor is trying to resolve when it loads the packages at startup?  Is it all related to versioning or is it actually looking at the code that you load with ap.use() in packages.js?

I am getting this error when I try to start up my project.  I have a super-simple package file that I created with the meter create --package command.  I put all of my files that make up the package into the directory that it created and moved that directory to .meteor/packages. I'm just trying to create a local package for now.  Here's the contents of package.js in that directory:

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'ammap-meteor',
  summary: 'mapping library packaged for meteor ',
  version: '1.0.0',

});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('METEOR@0.9.0');
  api.addFiles('ammap.js');
  api.addFiles('ammap_amcharts_extension.js');
});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('tinytest');
  api.use('ammap-meteor');
  api.addFiles('ammap-meteor-tests.js');
});
```

My ammap-meteor-tests.js file is blank for the moment but it exists.  Would that make a difference?  And I assume you just omit the git: property from Package.onUse() for a local package, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was able to get past that error with the publish command:

```
meteor publish --create
```

So I did not succeed in making a local package (still not clear on that) but at least I can get the package to load now.